# What's wrong with this random number guessing game?

Tags: javascript, html, random

I made a random number guessing game in which you can determine the maximum value and the minimum value. I checked my entire code twice but can't seem to find a solution to why it won't work. I made this script linked to a HTML file that explains the `document.getElementById("randNum").innerHTML` part.
I also want to say I am very new to coding so I might've overlooked something simple. Anyways, here's my code.

```
var max = prompt("Max guessing number?");

if (max <= 2) {
  document.getElementById("randNum").innerHTML = "Invalid entry";
} else {

  var min = prompt("What's the smallest number you can guess?");
  if (min >= (max - 1) || min <= 0) {
    document.getElementById("randNum").innerHTML = "Invalid entry";

  } else {

    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);

    guess = prompt("What's your guess?");

    if (guess > max || guess < min) {

      document.getElementById("randNum").innerHTML = "Invalid entry";

    } else if (guess == number) {

      document.getElementById("randNum").innerHTML = "Good job! You guessed the number!";

    } else {

      document.getElementById("randNum").innerHTML = "Wrong! The answer was " + number + "!";

    }
  }
}
```

EDIT: I changed how the random number generator works but I'm still getting an error. And to add more detail, the page says Invalid entry

Comment: Are you getting errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

The data type returned by `prompt` is string, so calculations might go wrong if you don't explicitly convert it to number.  You can do this by applying the unitary `+` operator, like `+prompt('....');`

Secondly, the way to get random numbers between *min* and *max* should be different. Change this:

```
number = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);
```

to:

```
number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
```

The corrected code:

```js
var max = +prompt("Max guessing number?");

if (max <= 2) {
  document.getElementById("randNum").innerHTML = "Invalid entry";
} else {

  var min = +prompt("Wat is het kleinste nummer dat je kan raden?");
  if (min >= (max - 1) || min <= 0) {
    document.getElementById("randNum").innerHTML = "Invalid entry";

  } else {

    number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    console.log(min, max, number, (max - min + 1));

    guess = +prompt("What's your guess?");

    if (guess > max || guess < min) {

      document.getElementById("randNum").innerHTML = "Invalid entry";

    } else if (guess == number) {

      document.getElementById("randNum").innerHTML = "Good job! You guessed the number!";

    } else {

      document.getElementById("randNum").innerHTML = "Wrong! The answer was " + number + "!";

    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="randNum" ></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be really wrong for me:

```
number = Math.floor((Math.random() * max) + min);
```

So, you are telling the random number generator to generate a number that is a maximum of `max` and add with it the `min` value. Say, if I give two numbers:

```
15, 18
```

And if the `Math.random() * max` is equal to `17`, then it becomes:

```
17 + 15 = 32
```

You might need to do this way:

```
number = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
```

The above code ensures that, the random number is not more than the difference between the `max` and `min`, and when we add the `min` with the value, we have the random number generated between the range.

This will make sure that the number is between `max` and `min`.